# How to create 7z archive with no compression using java

Tags: java, zip, 7zip

now we are using library zip4j to create archive with no compression:

```
ZipFile zipSoubor = new ZipFile("test.zip");
```

and when I want to stream I use:

```
zipSoubor.addStream(bis, getDefaultZipParameters());
```

and

```
private ZipParameters getDefaultZipParameters() {
    ZipParameters zipParametre = new ZipParameters();
    zipParametre.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_STORE);
    zipParametre.setSourceExternalStream(true);
    zipParametre.setEncryptFiles(true);
    zipParametre.setEncryptionMethod(Zip4jConstants.ENC_METHOD_AES);
    zipParametre.setAesKeyStrength(Zip4jConstants.AES_STRENGTH_256);
    zipParametre.setPassword(heslo);

    return zipParametre;
}
```

problem is when I open this archive in mc (F3) I see type is zip. I need to create archive with type 7z. Is there some option how to create it in java ?

Comment: hm I dont know why ? I just want to copy all file to one archive with no compression

Comment: The option `-m0` would imply `Copy`, i.e. no compression.

Comment: Did you read my post ? I know how to created it with program 7z but now I need to create it using java

Comment: There is a [Java SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) available.  Do you want us to write the code for you?

Comment: nope, I just ask if there is option in zip4j. Please read my question before write comment. LZMA is compresion method and I ask with no compression

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons Compress (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/) added preliminary support for writing 7z files.